# Problema con ruta Agular (no actualiza datos)

Tags: angular, rutas

Tengo un problema, tengo un componente que muestra los datos de usuario, como una especie de perfil, le envio la ID del usuario por url parecido a esto "users/1", "users/2" esta id se envía y recibe al backend para identificar que perfil se va a mostrar o actualizar, el problema llega en el momento que intento cambiar de ruta "users/1" a "users/2" (tengo un panel a la derecha que me muestra los usuarios y va directamente de la ruta 1 a la 2) por tanto.. es como si no notase ningún cambio en la ruta y no hace de nuevo la petición al back para obtener los nuevos datos.

```
private id = this.rutaActiva.snapshot.params.id;
```

de esta forma recibo la id de la url, posteriormente ya envio la petición GET al back para obtener los datos de esa ID pero al cambiar la id en la url no me lanza la nueva petición.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ocupar los observables que da la clase ActivedRoute para identificar si hay algún cambio en la url.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(parameter => {
      const paramId = parameter.id;
      this.someService(paramId).subscribe(response => this.data = response);
    });
  }
```

En la [documentacion oficial](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#description) viene lo siguiente:

> Nota: los observables de esta clase sólo emiten cuando los valores actuales y anteriores difieren en base a una igualdad superficial. Por ejemplo, el cambio de propiedades profundamente anidadas en datos resueltos no hará que el Observable ActivatedRoute.data emita un nuevo valor.

En este caso puede ser util ya que no tienes una url tan compleja